# ASP.NET nTier Architecutre

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

I have a project which require me to set up a web application using the ntier approach. However, as most of the projects that i did was a website using 1 tier, therefore i am foreign to this architecture.

I have decided to set up a 3 Tier architecture, Presentation Tier, Business & Data Access Tier
and lastly the Data Tier.

I would like to know, since these tiers are in different server machine, how are they suppose to communicate? Would using Web Service helps solve this?

Is there any simple tutorials or lessons where this is totally taught? From building the applications to deploying on separate server machines.

Comment: You might get some inspiration from http://tinyurl.com/d99w8rl. Examples are C#, but it's more about the concepts that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think is a good tutorial. I suggest you to use MVC 4 for your project and follow the logic below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439688/Creating-ASP-NET-application-with-n-tier-architect

Answer (score 0):

Use the followings:
Presentation Layer --> By creating Asp.Net Project 
Business Logic & Data Access Layer --> By Creating Web Service Project. 
SQL Database --> By Creating a new DB in the machine you installed SQL.

Once you done:

1. Design your database tables in your SQL Studio.
2. In BL & DAL Project connect to your SQL DB using Entity Framework, this will create a ready to use scheme and actually will generate a DAL automatically with all the business objects you need.
3. In BL create the method signatures (definition) for all the methods that should be implemented.
4. In your presentation Layer add service reference to your BL & DAL Web Service.

It will take time and you will need to read a lot about Entity Framework and Web Services and how to utilize those to your needs.

Comment: Hi G.Y! Currently i created a sample project to simulate the nTier architecture. I have a solution with 3 projects, a BLL, a PL and a WebService project. So, the aspx.vb file in the PL project/tier will call a WebService function which will call then call the function in the BLL project/tier. I was thinking of separating the PL project to one server machine and the BLL & Webservice project to another server machine. Do I need to configure anything in order for the PL Tier to be able to call the Webservice function?

Answer (score 0):

If they are on separate machines then the common scenario using Microsoft technologies would be:

1. `User Interface` (UI) implemented by `ASP.NET`
2. `Business Layer` (BLL) implemented by `C#` or `VB` `.NET`
   as bunch of DLLs
3. `Data Access Layer` (DAL) as a relational database i.e. a `SQL`
   database with it's tables, stored procedures... plus classes (Some
   DLLs) to access database. Best practice is using `ORMs` i.e. `Entity
   Framework` to handle `Data Access Layer` and `Data Layer`.

Your layers in common scenario will communicate to each other this way:

- Your `UI` will communicate to `BLL` commonly using `Web Services`.
- Your `BLL` will communicate to `DAL` commonly using `Web Services`.
- Your `DAL` will communicate to `Database` commonly using `TCP/IP`.

Although `n-Tier` design is the best practice, it doesn't mean each layer should be hosted on different machine (consider it more a logical separation than physical). For example if you keep all 3 layers on the same machine and just host your database on a different server then you don't need implementing web-services for `BLL` and `DAL` which results in less complexity and time-to-implement plus other benefits i.e. higher communication speed and security.